# (MonoGame) Creating multiple instances of one object

Tags: c#, object, xna, instance, monogame

I want to make a Box object, so i can make multiple instances of it.

I need to make the box show texture and detect intersections etc.

How would I do this so I could make a method like this.

```
addBox(x, y);
```

Without having to add anything to Update() and other areas?

Thanks.

Comment: Find a tutorial and follow it until you understand the basics of C# and XNA/MonoGame

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please don't post requirements as we are not a code-writing service.  Thanks

Comment: Suggestions and tips would have sufficed.

Man why is everyone so negative here.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to loop over all added boxes in update and draw. Example:

```
class Box
{
    vector2d Postion;
    public Box(vector2d _position)
    {
        Position = _position;
    }
}

class Boxes : list<Box>
{

    public void AddBox(Position)
    {
        this.add(new Box(Position));
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        foreach (Box b in this) {
            //b.position += b.velocity
        }
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        foreach (Box b in this) {
            //draw b
        }
    }
}


Boxes.AddBox(vecor2d(200,300))
```

Comment: true. changed. don't know c# but i tried to convert it.... oh, it looks quite same as VB version. sorcery!

Comment: @DavorMlinaric This won't compile.  What is `vector2d` and `list<>`? Casing?  Also `Position` is inaccessible to `Boxes` due to the former being `private`.

Comment: i dont know C#.i posted in VB at first place but then convert code from VB to C# using online tool, not sure if is correct. also question owner should first look into some basics for c# and then start in XNA.

Comment: What I was mainly wondering is that if you would draw and update everything within the class. I guess this anwsers my question?